# update a part of field using matching id from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with following data
(here key field comprises of site__marker)

```
  id     userid              key                value
   1       1                site_1_name         http://example1.com
   2       1                site_1_user         user1
   3       1                site_2_name         http://example2.com
   4       2                site_1_name         http://example3.com
   5       2                site_1_user         user2
```

and I have site mapping table

```
 oldsiteid      newsiteid
     1              120
     2              152
```

Now I need to update first table in way that only  values updates in key field
 should match oldsiteid in second table, and should get updated by newsiteid

Output should be like

```
  id     userid              key                value
   1       1                site_120_name         http://example1.com
   2       1                site_120_user         user1
   3       1                site_152_name         http://example2.com
   4       2                site_120_name         http://example3.com
   5       2                site_120_user         user2
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Is the structure of those tables carved into stone or can they be changed? If the mapping table isn't used in any other way, I'd change the data in to to refer exactly to the value of your key `field` (aka _site_1_name_ and such), which would make this rather simple. Otherwise its quite painful to work around this.

Comment: Your first table is not in [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) because the intersection of row and column `key` is not a scalar value, hence your data is not relational, therefore it is not suited to being updated using SQL. Fix the design first.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to translate this REXX in SQL, the functions are staight forward:

```
old = 'user_1_ddd' 
n = "333"
new = substr(a,1,index(a,"_")) || n || substr(a,index(a,"_") + index(substr(a, index(a,"_")+1)  ,"_"))
```

results in user_333_ddd

substr is the same in both

for index, use Find_in_set

for || use concat

Answer (score 0):

I do not have MySQL but this should work:

```
UPDATE  TargetTable
SET key = CONCAT
    ( 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(key,'_',1)
        ,'_'
        , (SELECT newsiteid FROM MappingTable WHERE MappingTable.oldsiteid =  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TargetTable.key,'_',-2), '_', 1 ))
        ,'_'
        ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(key,'_',-1) 
    )
```